# Cannot extract the contents of variables from while loop in java

Tags: java

I have a problem getting the contents of these 2 variables: n1 and n2, outside of the while loop. Here is my code snippet:

```
 try{
            InputStream flux = new FileInputStream("file.txt"); 
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(flux);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
            String ligne, ligne1;
 
            while ((ligne = buff.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(ligne.startsWith("k"))
                {
                    first = Integer.parseInt(ligne.substring(6, 9));
                    second = Integer.parseInt(ligne.substring(10, 13));
                }             
            }
 
            while ((ligne1 = buff.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(ligne1.startsWith("e"))
                {
                    int ind1 = ligne1.lastIndexOf(" ");
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt(ligne1.substring(2, ind1));
                    n2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne1.substring(ind1+1));
                }
            }
            ...
           // Displaying of their content
            System.out.println(first); // ok
            System.out.println(second); // ok
            System.out.println(n1); // doesn't work content 0
            System.out.println(n2); // doesn't work content 0
```

I don't want to display their content in while loop.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why does `System.out.println(n1);` work "ok", but then `System.out.println(n1);` "doesn't work content 0"?

Comment: Error, it was second. I already corrected that.

Comment: What is the input? What do you expect? What do you get? Where are n1, n2, first and second declared?

Comment: Input is a text file. I expect to have the real values of n1 and n2. First and second are declared above, like that : String first =0, second = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Transfert the `System.out.println` into your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You read the entire buffer to populate `first` and `second`:

```
while ((ligne = buff.readLine())!=null)
{ ... }
```

and then try to get more lines from the buffer to populate `n1` and `n2`:

```
while ((ligne = buff.readLine())!=null)
{ ... }
```

Of course, the buffer is now empty - you read all the lines in the first loop. So, the loop body is never executed, and so `n1` and `n2` are never set.

Put the contents of the second loop inside the first:

```
        while ((ligne = buff.readLine())!=null)
        {
            if(ligne.startsWith("k"))
            {
                first = Integer.parseInt(ligne.substring(6, 9));
                second = Integer.parseInt(ligne.substring(10, 13));
            }

            /* else */ if (ligne.startsWith("e"))
            {
                int ind1 = ligne1.lastIndexOf(" ");
                n1 = Integer.parseInt(ligne1.substring(2, ind1));
                n2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne1.substring(ind1+1));
            }
        }
```

or re-open `buff` before the second loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answere! So, I can't put the contents of the second loop inside the first because I want to use them out of the loop. I just tried your second proposition but it didn't  work. Perhaps I made a mistake. Can you please give me a exemple? I'm a beginner in java.

Comment: You must have done it wrong. Putting the second loop in the first doesn't restrict the scope of any of the variables in either the first or second loop. I've expanded the `...` in my answer, but really, it's just copying+pasting.

Comment: That's what I've done but I still have the same problem

Comment: If I would separate those loops, it's because I want to use the values of n1and n2 as parameters of a function in the second loop.